# Webclient.DownloadFile to Folderbrowser.Selectedpath

Tags: vb.net, dialog, webclient

I want my code to download a file from a website and save it to an directory that the user has selected in the FolderBrowserDialog ... i've tried this code below without success:
`' Download the files
        If My.Computer.Network.IsAvailable Then
            Try
    wClient.DownloadFile(New Uri("DOWNLOAD LINK"), FolderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath & "FILENAME.123")
wClient.DownloadFile(New Uri("DOWNLOAD LINK"), FolderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath & "FileName.123)
wClient.DownloadFile(New Uri("Download LINK"), FolderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath & "FileName.123")
            Catch ex As Exception
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
 End Try`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is some sample code I have written for you that should get you started.
first we declare `wClient` as a `WebClient` with `Events` so we can trigger what happens when the file downloads.
I have used VLC Media Player as an example download, change to suit your needs. NOTE I did this with a button click event which you don't necessary need to do.

```
Imports System.ComponentModel
Imports System.Net
Public Class Form1
Private WithEvents wClient As New WebClient()
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    Dim FolderBrowserDiaglog1 As New FolderBrowserDialog()
    Dim folderPath As String = ""
    Dim fileName As String = "vlc.exe"

    Dim downloadFile As String = "https://get.videolan.org/vlc/2.2.6/win32/vlc-2.2.6-win32.exe" ''VLC MEDIA PLAYER
    If FolderBrowserDiaglog1.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.OK Then
        folderPath = FolderBrowserDiaglog1.SelectedPath
    End If
    If My.Computer.Network.IsAvailable Then
        Dim combinePath As String = System.IO.Path.Combine(folderPath, fileName)
        wClient.DownloadFileAsync(New Uri(downloadFile), combinePath)
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub wClient_DownloadFileCompleted(sender As Object, e As AsyncCompletedEventArgs) Handles wClient.DownloadFileCompleted
    MessageBox.Show("File Downloaded")
End Sub
End Class
```

Have a look in the `wClient`'s event list and see the many options that are avalible such as the one that i have made that shows a messagebox once the file has been downloaded.
Webclient events https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient_events(v=vs.110).aspx