# how to download exe files in vb.net (Visual Studio 2015)

Tags: vb.net

I try make one program for download one .exe file and run for help in my job.
But idk how to make this, i'm new in VB.

I am using this code, as shown in the [Visual Basic document reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ack30t8y(v=vs.90).aspx#Anchor_4):

```
My.Computer.Network.DownloadFile _
("http://www.cohowinery.com/downloads/WineList.txt", _
"C:\Documents and Settings\All Users\Documents\WineList.txt")
```

But when I try to download an .exe file, the entire file doesn't complete and I the file is only 1 kb after download.

Comment: Not sure what you're asking. And your code shows you downloading a text file, not a .exe file.

Comment: @DavidMakogon i asking how to download a .exe file from a website

Comment: Its only one exemple

Comment: Here is how to do it with a webclient https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45046899/webclient-downloadfile-to-folderbrowser-selectedpath/45047447#45047447

Answer (score 0):

The webclient should be the way to go a comment above highlights that too.

This is an example from another question:

Either use sync method:

```
public void DownloadFile()
{
    using(var client = new WebClient())
    {
        client.DownloadFile(new Uri("http://www.FileServerFullOfFiles.net/download/test.exe"), "test.exe");
    }
}
```

Or use new async-await approach:

```
public async Task DownloadFileAsync()
{
    using(var client = new WebClient())
    {
        await client.DownloadFileTaskAsync(new Uri("http://www.FileServerFullOfFiles.net/download/test.exe"), "test.exe");
    }
}
```

Then call this method like this:

```
await DownloadFileAsync();
```

Answer (score 0):

Open up the .exe file you are trying to download in a text editor like NotePad. Odds are what is being downloaded is an HTML page showing some kind of error message like `404 not found`.

Another possibility might be that AntiVirus software is moving the original EXE into quarantine and replacing it with a Quarantine MetaData file.

If the file does actually contain binary content your connection could be getting interrupted but odds are if this happened an exception would be thrown.